# Opimizing Code in android

Tags: java, android, performance

I am implementing a calendar app where i can add events to this calendar.
I have two button where previous button shows the previous month and next button shows the next month.
Each button click compile the below code:

```
private void makingCalenderDataList(int mm, int yy) {

    // clear previous data
    list.clear();

    int trailingSpaces = 0;
    int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
    int prevMonth = 0;
    int prevYear = 0;
    int nextMonth = 0;
    int nextYear = 0;

    int currentSelectedMonth = mm - 1;
    // String currentMonthName = mData.getMonthAsString(currentSelectedMonth);
    daysInMonth = mData.getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentSelectedMonth);

    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentSelectedMonth, 1);
   // Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

    if (currentSelectedMonth == 11) {
        prevMonth = currentSelectedMonth - 1;
        daysInPrevMonth = mData.getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
        nextMonth = 0;
        prevYear = yy;
        nextYear = yy + 1;
        // Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:" + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
    } else if (currentSelectedMonth == 0) {
        prevMonth = 11;
        prevYear = yy - 1;
        nextYear = yy;
        daysInPrevMonth = mData.getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
        nextMonth = 1;
        // Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:" + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
    } else {
        prevMonth = currentSelectedMonth - 1;
        nextMonth = currentSelectedMonth + 1;
        nextYear = yy;
        prevYear = yy;
        daysInPrevMonth = mData.getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
        //  Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:" + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
    }

    int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;


    if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
        if (mm == 2)
            ++daysInMonth;
        else if (mm == 3)
            ++daysInPrevMonth;


    // Trailing Month days
    for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {

        list.add(String
                .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                        + i)
                + "-Trailing"
                + "-"
                + mData.getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                + "-"
                + prevYear);
    }


    // Current Month Days
    for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {

        //  Log.d("imon", "monthOfCurrentDate: " + monthOfCurrentDate + " monthOfCurrentDate " + (currentSelectedMonth + 1));
        // if the date is today's date then make it different color
        if (i == mData.getCurrentDayOfMonth() && monthOfCurrentDate == (currentSelectedMonth + 1)) {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-Today" + "-"
                    + mData.getMonthAsString(currentSelectedMonth) + "-" + yy);


        }
        // if current month == from month
        // then we have to check whether the CurrentDateDay is greater than or equal fromDateDay
        else if ((currentSelectedMonth + 1) == Integer.parseInt(fromDateMonth)) {
            if ((i >= Integer.parseInt(fromDateDay))) {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-Events" + "-"
                        + mData.getMonthAsString(currentSelectedMonth) + "-" + yy);
            } else {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-CurrentMonth" + "-"
                        + mData.getMonthAsString(currentSelectedMonth) + "-" + yy);
            }

        }
        // if current month > from month && current month <To month
        // then we don't have to check
        // all days will be enlisted as events
        else if ((currentSelectedMonth + 1) > Integer.parseInt(fromDateMonth) && (currentSelectedMonth + 1) < Integer.parseInt(toDateMonth)) {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-Events" + "-"
                    + mData.getMonthAsString(currentSelectedMonth) + "-" + yy);

        }
        //  current month == To month
        // then we have to check whether the CurrentDateDay is smaller than or equal toDateDay
        else if ((currentSelectedMonth + 1) == Integer.parseInt(toDateMonth)) {
            if ((i <= Integer.parseInt(toDateDay))) {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-Events" + "-"
                        + mData.getMonthAsString(currentSelectedMonth) + "-" + yy);
            } else {
                list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-CurrentMonth" + "-"
                        + mData.getMonthAsString(currentSelectedMonth) + "-" + yy);
            }

        } else {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-CurrentMonth" + "-"
                    + mData.getMonthAsString(currentSelectedMonth) + "-" + yy);
        }
    }


    // Leading Month days
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
        Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + mData.getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
        list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-LeadingDates" + "-"
                + mData.getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
    }

    if (list.size() == 42) {
        mWeek6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        mWeek6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

It works fine but my problem is that if i click frequently in the two buttons then the calendar gets slow.

How can i optimize these code?
if anybody can help then it would be very helpful.

Comment: Disable the button till this method finishes execution and at the end again enable that.

Comment: It will not meet the proper solution .

Comment: In `// Current Month Days` you are using too much loop and if-else. This makes your application slow. You should disable the button like @ShreeKrishna or optimize code (why you don't change to other ways). I don't know this code, so I can't help you.

Comment: @kkkk If this doesn't meet the proper solution then Don't click the button frequently.

Comment: You should profile the code to see where it is spending most of the time.